# RouteTable: None in AWS Boto get_all_route_tables()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto, amazon-vpc

When I grab all route tables using:

`conn=boto.vpc.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
 c=conn.get_all_route_tables()`

output contains multiple list items of `RouteTable:None` in addition to route table ids I expect:

`[RouteTable:rtb-123xyzz,
 RouteTable:rtb-456abcc,
 RouteTable:None,
 RouteTable:None,
 RouteTable:None,`

Can someone tell why these none items are included in the output?
With them in there, I am not able to iterate over to get more attribute/value info.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why some route table ids are `None`. It could be the route table creation was aborted. But iterating through them is your issue, you can do:

- Delete those route tables
- Ignore those route tables

It is easy to ignore them in python:

```
for rt in c:
  if rt.id  # Valid route table id
    # Do your stuff
```

Or just filter out the `None` route tables:

```
route_tables = [rt for rt in c if rt.id]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I now have route table ids, and internet gateway ids. How should I describe route tables so I can check if they have igw in them?  Eventually I will create a list of public subnets by checking route table associations. Trying to find the correct syntax. Thank you.

Comment: It is totally different from the question you asked initially. Post it as a different question after accepting the answer.